# Configuration Save Unauthorized Access

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I am writing a C# application in Visual Studio which needs to save some settings for persistence so that the user doesn't need to enter them every time they start the application.

To this end, I have created a class `ConfigurationController` which uses the standard `System.Configuration` library and App.config to store settings.

I have the following method to actually save the settings in `<appSettings>` with keys

```
internal void Save(string name, string value)
{
    if (AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(name))
    {
        AppSettings.Remove(name);
    }
    AppSettings.Add(name, value);

    Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

I am having a problem, whereby when `Config.Save()` is called, it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` with the message 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'

I thought that perhaps this was because the project was on a network share, but I copied a release build to my local machine and still had this problem. I tried running as Administrator, and ensured my user took ownership of the folder the application was in. I can't seem to find the problem. Everything belongs to my user, and I have full control, but still for some reason the application doesn't have access to modify the config file?

Is there anything I can look at that might give some more detail or indication of what exactly is happening?

Here is a minimal viable product. If I load this in a visual studio project on my local disk then there is no problem. However, if I load off the network share I get the exception thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

namespace UnauthorizedErrorExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigurationController.Instance.Save("Setting", "Value");
        }
    }

    internal class ConfigurationController
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration Config;
        KeyValueConfigurationCollection AppSettings;

        private static ConfigurationController instance;

        private ConfigurationController()
        {
            Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            AppSettings = Config.AppSettings.Settings;
        }

        public static ConfigurationController Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if(instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ConfigurationController();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        internal string GetValue(string name)
        {
            return AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(name) ? AppSettings[name].Value : "";
        }

        internal T GetValue<T>(string name)
        {
            return AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(name) ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(AppSettings[name].Value, typeof(T)) : default(T);
        }

        internal void Save(string name, string value)
        {
            if (AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(name))
            {
                AppSettings.Remove(name);
            }
            AppSettings.Add(name, value);

            Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a mininal viable example? eg so we can paste in and recreate..

Comment: @BugFinder I have just done so and in doing so I have found that if I load the project from my local disk, I don't have a problem. If I copy the project to the network share and load it from there the problem occurs again

Comment: Check config.FilePath and see where that says its trying to write to when you run it from network share.